# Oracle Insert query takes long time in Production but performs in 3 seconds in lower environment

Tags: oracle, performance

In my Oracle stored procedure I have a SQL query which takes very long in production but in lower environment it takes only about 3-4 seconds. Please note this query is in loop and runs for 7000 times. I have no choice other than the loop as this involves lots of logic to validate the data and can't move it to simple query.

```
    INSERT INTO GTT_POSTING_XX (meter_id,
                            period_id,
                            period_duration,
                            meter_value,
                            meter_date,
                            expected_count)
WITH
    inputs
    AS
        (SELECT :rmeter                       rmeter,
                :oldmeter                     oldmeter,
                :rmaxreaddate                 rmaxreaddate,
                :parm_value                   parm_value,
                :end_date                     end_date,
                :swap_date                    swap_date,
                :period_duration              period_duration
           FROM DUAL),
    im
    AS
        (SELECT 
                meter_id,
                meter_period_id,
                meter_period_duration,
                meter_value,
                meter_date
           FROM meter_f imf, inputs i
          WHERE meter_id = i.rmeter
            AND meter_date BETWEEN i.swap_date + 1 AND i.end_date - i.parm_value
            AND meter_period_duration = NVL (i.period_duration, meter_period_duration))
SELECT IM.METER_ID,
       IM.METER_PERIOD_ID,
       IM.METER_PERIOD_DURATION,
       IM.METER_VALUE,
       IM.METER_DATE,
       IP.PERIOD_COUNT
  FROM IM, PERIOD_D IP
 WHERE IP.PERIOD_ID       = IM.METER_PERIOD_ID
   AND IP.PERIOD_DURATION = IM.METER_PERIOD_DURATION
```

The above query was part of the dynamic SQL and I picked it from the TOAD's session browser so you will see those bind variables. Also note all the tables used in the query are created with parallel degree of 4 by the previous developer.

My entire process takes hardly 2 minutes in Dev and more than 20 minutes in Production. I am sure when it works in Dev and not in production, there should be configuration difference and reached my DBA already. DBA identified this as low SGA and PGA, AMM disabled, and Huge Pages enabled. But still issue is not resolved. I am not a DBA and not sure of the parameters to that caused this issue and below is what I got from my DBA after the changes.

```
    show parameter 

NAME TYPE VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
use_large_pages string ONLY

memory_max_target big integer 0
memory_target big integer 0

sga_target big integer 29G
ga_aggregate_target big integer 12G

optimizer_index_caching integer 90
optimizer_index_cost_adj integer 10

grep Huge /proc/meminfo
AnonHugePages: 0 kB
HugePages_Total: 14875
HugePages_Free: 25
HugePages_Rsvd: 0
HugePages_Surp: 0
Hugepagesize: 2048 kB
```

**Oracle Version**

```
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production    0
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production  0
CORE    12.1.0.2.0  Production  0
TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production  0
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production  0
```

Appreciate your help in advance and Thank You for reading!

Comment: If this is a problem with a single query, you should start by comparing the execution plans on both environments. Use these queries to find the SQL_ID and the execution plan, and then edit your answer and add both plans: `select * from gv$sql where lower(sql_text) like '%gtt_posting_xx %';`, `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor('SQL_ID from above query', cursor_child_no => null));`

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if this is related, but `optimizer_index_cost_adj integer 10` is a red flag. This parameter is telling the optimizer, "indexes run 10 times faster on this database than the average database." Is there really something special about your system that makes your indexes faster than average? In my experience, that parameter is set just to fix a single bad query by someone who thinks "indexes are always better than full table scans", which then unintentionally slows down many other queries.

Comment: Is there any triggers on the table `GTT_POSTING_XX` in both environments? Also for `dbms_xplan` it will be good to add `format => 'ALLSTATS LAST'` to identify if there're any huge IO/temp that can cause cause low performance with the same plan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, Since yesterday I started facing the same issue in my Dev env also. I was forced to research again and found the below link was really helpful and seems to have solved my problem atleast in DEv env for now, still got to try in Production.. I removed the Insert into GTT and made it a simple CTE but still the culprit was dynamic sampling by Oracle.

https://chinaraliyev.wordpress.com/2018/04/30/a-real-life-performance-issue-due-to-adaptive-dynamic-sampling/

Once again Thank you all for trying to help me. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

there are some considerations:

1. does the same data volume between the production and the dev? If there are 10k data in the dev while there are 10M data in the production env, it does make sense of the slowness in the production env.
2. the target SQL statement is divided two parts: DB engine firstly select the data,then insert the data into table GTT_POSTING_XX. Please find which part is the bottleneck from the execution plan. If the insert part is slow, please check if there are indexes in this table GTT_POSTING_XX; if does, please disable these indexes before insert; after insert, please enable these indexes.
   if the select part is slow, please check if table meter_f has index on column meter_id,meter_date and meter_period_duration. Please assure execution plan can leverage these indexes on table meter_f.

Answer (score 0):

You can greatly simplify your query to remove the sub-query factoring clauses, to use ANSI joins (rather than the legacy comma joins) and to directly use the bind variables:

```sql
INSERT INTO GTT_POSTING_XX (
  meter_id,
  period_id,
  period_duration,
  meter_value,
  meter_date,
  expected_count
)
SELECT m.METER_ID,
       m.METER_PERIOD_ID,
       m.METER_PERIOD_DURATION,
       m.METER_VALUE,
       m.METER_DATE,
       IP.PERIOD_COUNT
FROM   meter_f m
       INNER JOIN PERIOD_D IP
       ON (    IP.PERIOD_ID       = m.METER_PERIOD_ID
           AND IP.PERIOD_DURATION = m.METER_PERIOD_DURATION )
WHERE  m.METER_ID = :rmeter
AND    m.METER_DATE BETWEEN :swap_date + 1 AND :end_date - :parm_value
AND    (   :period_duration IS NULL
       OR  m.meter_period_duration = :period_duration
       )
```

This may or may not change the performance (depending on how Oracle was handling the sub-query factoring clauses) but it should make the query simpler to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

First of all apologies for the delay and then Thanks for all your kind responses.

Let clarify few things from your suggestions or questions, There are no indexes, constraints and triggers on my GTT. We have similar amount of data in both envs but the problem is with the servers, We identified this client works on a VM with very low configuration like 8 CPUs where as Dev has 28 CPUs and there are other issues which DBA is now analyzing too.

We performed this process in multiple DBs like QA, UAT and there was no issue except in production. Also since yesterday I was fine tuning this procedure to avoid using the GTT which had few couple of inserts and few updates for no reason and this even gave me better performance in my Dev env.